# what is the symbolism of the floating sword over the Vatican?

Tags: symbolism, trinity-blood

when we see the Vatican in *Trinity Blood*, one thing that makes it stand out (compared to the irl version) is that it has a floating sword

[image]
[image]

at first i thought this might have been a Sword of Damocles but generally when there is a Sword of Damocles reference, the sword is a threat ie. in *Code Geass*

> the Sword of Damocles's purpose was to float above earth to be able to nuke anything and everything no matter where

but in the images we see of this floating sword over the Vatican, it looks like the sword, if dropped, would just drop infront of the entrance rather than on the Vatican building, so the symbolism is sorta lost if it was a Sword of Damocles.

So i am wondering what the symbolism is of this floating sword, and if it is a Sword of Damocles, how exactly is it a Sword of Damocles?

Comment: Haven't seen the anime but as a Roman Catholic, this looks more like a cross than a sword. Crosses are prevalent symbols in our religion and it probably wouldn't be an overstatement to say it is the center of our belief as it represents the crucifixion of Jesus. You see them all the time in churches and holy places of worship at the most prominent places where lots of people can see it. If this is the Vatican, then it wouldn't be surprising, for a believer at least, to see a cross over it.